# Sql find duplicates in filed two IF field one is unique

Tags: sql

Trying to wrap my head around this but its just spinning in circles...

I have a sql right now and get to a point where I have values as such:

```
select T1.col1, T2.col2 
from T2, T1 
where T2.recNo = T1.recNo 
  AND T2.id=3 
  AND T1.recNo IN(
    select recNo from T1 where col1 IN (
      select col1 from T1 group by col1 having COUNT(*) >2))

col1|col2
111|123
111|123
222|456
222|456
222|456
333|789
333|700
```

etc...

This is a pretty large output and what I am trying to find is if there are any values in col2 that are NOT the same for each grouping of values in col1 (i know for certain col1 is unique) I dumped the output to a file and will try to figure it out in perl next.

The output i am trying to get is:

```
col1|col2
333|789
333|700
```

Comment: It would help to see a little more stuff. Your SQL query for example. And the desired output, as in, what qualifies for `not the same...`.

Comment: I added the sql that gets me where I am now and the ouput.

Comment: Will `333|789` still be part of your output if there is another line with that after the one with `700`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select col1
from (<your query here>) s
group by col1
having min(col2) <> max(col2);
```

This will return all `col1` values that have more than one `col2` value.